# 3D Model is not looking same as size in ARKit

Tags: swift, unity-game-engine, arkit, 3dsmax, .obj

**Problem statement**

I  am facing a trouble in AR that our model size does not match with real products.This iPhone has the same dimension as real iPhone but it doesn't match with real products.

> IPhone Model Size -  (5.44 x 2.64 x 0.28 in)

**Reference Screenshot**

[image: iPhone 7 in ARKit]

Reference .obj file [Download obj](https://d2ww3metzfrng3.cloudfront.net/demo/product/KTZRiRjvhW2uCCnRd.obj)

Comment: What happens when you scale down the object? Does dimensions match?

Comment: Yes, it's working by manually adjusting the height and width of the model. We might need to compromise the visual quality as we are doing it manually without perfect dimension.

We need a solution, so we can create the model with perfect dimension, and it should display the model perfectly in AR along with original product side by side.

Answer (score 4):

It's highly likely that the scale of the `.obj` is not correct.

If you load your model into the `SceneKit Editor`, and click on the 'cube' on the right hand side:

[image]

You will see in the `transforms section` an area which says `Bounding Box`.

You can check here to see if your model is actually the right size:

[image]

In my example my model is an `SCNPlane` with a `width` and `height` of 0.1m (10cm).

If your bounding box is then not correct, you will need to set the `scale` which can be done using the `scale` property of an `SCNNode` e.g:

```
model.scale = SCNVector3(0.1, 0.1, 0.1)
```

Whereby:

> Each component of the scale vector multiplies the corresponding
>   dimension of the node’s geometry. The default scale is 1.0 in all
>   three dimensions. For example, applying a scale of (2.0, 0.5, 2.0) to
>   a node containing a cube geometry reduces its height and increases its
>   width and depth.

Hope it helps...

Comment: This is a good suggestion. Can we do it without doing any manual work? Can't we do it automatically via programming?